# Why I can not delete a NSManagedObject?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I use the method `“deleteObject:”` to delete a `NSManagedObject`, but after this I still can print the `NSManagedObject` although it no longer associates with any other `NSManagedObject`.

How lead to this and why?

Answer (score 0):

deleteObject: will delete the parameter NSManagedObject from the context. That doesn't mean it will make your object be nil. In fact, it has no way of doing so as you're passing a reference and not the address of it. Most likely it's already doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I need seriously study the Core Data frame, but where can I find some detailed material about it?

Comment: The documentation by apple is the best place to look: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html